# IIS Express keeps creating website copies

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I'm developing a Web API using VS2012. In order to allow my mates access the api in the same LAN, I need to modify the `applicationhost.config` file.

The problem is that sometimes when I modify the code and start debugging, I found that IIS Express created a copy of my application, say `MyWebAPI(1), MyWebAPI(2)...` Then I have to modify the `applicationhost.config` again.

Does anyone know in which case IIS Express will create a copy of my application?

Here is an example of what my `applicationhost.config`:

```
        <site name="MyWebAPI(1)" id="15">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Example\example" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="SunPower(2)" id="16">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Example\example" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:*" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```